# What are the advantages of a page-wrapping div and should I use one anyway?

Tags: html, css

I'm mainly a back-end programmer but every now and then I need to put a human-friendly face over something, and end up becoming a web designer/dev for a day.

More than a few times my layout issues have been solved with wrapping **everything** in a div directly inside the `<body>` tags and applying some styling to that, mainly sticky footers or pushing content down to fill *at least* the height of the viewport. Because I use I use it infrequently, I tend to forget the intricacies of HTML/CSS, but I'm wondering **should I always wrap all body content in a div as good practice?**

On one hand:

- It seems to be the most commonly suggested solution to stretching content all the way down (sidebars also seem to be a menace for this).
- Even if I don't need it to start with, I may need it in future, and putting it there to start with means it is less likely to affect the rest of the page if I need to add one later.

But I feel like there's enough I don't know about web page rendering that overall it could be detrimental somehow. Is it semantic? Does it open up the potential for bigger problems with other parts of the page? I like clean code and I like scanning through my work and be able to tell at a glance what everything does and why it is there. Something just feels off to me about a div whose purpose is not immediately clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not that you have to wrap body content with div. It just historically web was about content only. You can trace it even how names has changed over time.

**Webpage** - page in web. Page like a book page, just simple text. Text has flow layout. Styling is minimal (in terms of location). It is not important what is underneath when content is finished, just the rest of blank page.

And now your already mention term **viewport**. It is place for **content** and **control elements**. Modern web-page not a classic page anymore, it is application nowadays. But term web-page already in use. Try to calculate how much of page space takes text content (flow layout) and the rest(buttons, images, video, controls - block layout) for example on Facebook

Element div become universal element used to split content logically into separate blocks. Element div just a block with max available width of his parent and height of inner content. The visual presentation of div element can be widely changed using styling. There are a lot of new semantic elements in html5 those were emulated by div element mostly previously. Easy to guess what for such elements like *header, footer, aside, nav...*

Main idea of div is to split content logically and style it as you need.